# What should I do to be able to run my function after I click on a mat-tab?

Tags: angular

I have a function in my component:

```
aaa(  ) {
    console.log('mat-tab')
}
```

I want to run my function when I click on a `mat-tab` I tried this code:

```
<mat-tab label="Tools" (click)="aaa( )">

</mat-tab>
```

but it is not working.

What should I do to be able to run my function after I click on a `mat-tab`?

Comment: Use `selectedTabChange` on `mat-tab-group`, `mat-tab` is removed and not loaded in DOM so `click` event will not get fire

Comment: @Sameer If I want to apply different functions to different `mat-tab`s, what should I do?

Comment: You will get `MatTabChangeEvent` as a parameter for `selectedTabChange`. That will contain `index` use that to call the required function. [Read More Here](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api#MatTabGroup)

Comment: @Sameer It would be great if you could give an example in your answer.

I tried this : `(selectedTabChange(MatTabChangeEvent[(0)]))="aaa( )"`

and it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen for tab change event and call respective functions accordingly

```html
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="changeTab($event)">
  <mat-tab label="First">Content 1</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second">Content 2</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third">Content 3</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

```js
changeTab(evt: MatTabChangeEvent) {
    console.log(evt); //{index: 1, tab: MatTab}
    if (evt.index === 0) {
      //first tab active
    } else if (evt.index === 1) {
      //second tab active
    }
  }
```

Note: `index` is zero based